# The context of "this" in Meteor template event handlers (using Handlebars for templating)

Tags: javascript, meteor, handlebars.js

A quick question on the context of the event handlers for templates in Meteor (with Handlebars).

- In the section of Documentation on template instances (http://docs.meteor.com/#template_inst) it is mentioned that "*Template instance objects are found as the value of this in the created, rendered, and destroyed template callbacks and **as an argument to event handlers***"
- In the Templates section (http://docs.meteor.com/#templates) it says "*Finally, you can use an events declaration on a template function to set up a table of event handlers. The format is documented at Event Maps. **The this argument** to the event handler will be the **data context** of the element that triggered the event.*"

Well, this is only partially true. Let's use an example from the docs:

```
<template name="scores">
  {{#each player}}
    {{> playerScore}}
  {{/each}}
</template>

<template name="playerScore">
  <div>{{name}}: {{score}}
    <span class="givePoints">Give points</span>
  </div>
</template
Template.playerScore.events({
  'click .givePoints': function () {
    Users.update({_id: this._id}, {$inc: {score: 2}});
  });
```

Here the "this" context of the 'click .givePoints' event handler is indeed the template instance of playerScore. Let's modify the html:

```
<template name="scores">
  <span class="click-me">Y U NO click me?<span>
  {{#each player}}
    {{> playerScore}}
  {{/each}}
</template>

<template name="playerScore">
  <div>{{name}}: {{score}}
    <span class="givePoints">Give points</span>
  </div>
</template>
```

... and add an event handler for .click-me on the scores template:

```
Template.scores.events({
  'click .click-me': function () {
    console.log(this);
  }
});
```

Now, if you click the span, what do you get logged? The Window object! What did I expect to get? The template object! Or maybe the data context, but it's neither. However, inside the callbacks (e.g. Template.scores.rendered = function(){ ... }) the context of "this" is always the template instance.

I guess my real question would be: is this something to do with

- a bug in Handlebars, Meteor or somewhere in between?
- slightly incomplete documentation on the templates?
- me completely misinterpreting the docs or not understanding something fundamental
  about Meteor or Handlebars?

Thanks!

Comment: That is a right question. I've always accessed data in the events using `function(event,template)`, and then through `template.data`.

Comment: Wish I could upvote it twice

Comment: @ТаняТ. you can mark the question as favorite, like I did ;-)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This video explains the concepts:

http://www.eventedmind.com/posts/meteor-spark-data-annotation-and-data-contexts.

The direct answer to your question:

The thisArg inside an event handler *should* point to a data context. But sometimes the data context is `undefined`. When you use the `Function.prototype.call(thisArg, ...)` in JavaScript, if the thisArg is undefined (e.g. a dataContext is undefined) the browser will set `this` equal to window. So, the docs aren't *wrong* per se but the event handling code isn't guarding against the possibility of a data context being undefined. I'm guessing that will be fixed in short order.

So, what produces a data context for a template? Normally your root template won't even have a data context. In other words, the Template function is called without an object. But if you use the `{{#with` block helper or the `{{#each` iterator, a data context will be created for each item in the list, or in the case of the *with* helper, the object.

Example:

```
var context = {};

<template name="withHelper">
  {{#with context}}
    // data context is the context object
  {{/with}}
</template>

var list = [ {name: "one"}, {name: "two"} ];

<template name="list">
  {{#each list}}
    {{ > listItem }} // data context set to the list item object
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

Comment: The data context getting set to `window` if the data context is undefined has been fixed in the latest version of Meteor. So, now `this` inside an event handler always points to an object, either the data context or an empty object if there is no data context.

Comment: Thanks for bringing it up :-).

Comment: I just updated to 0.5.9 and I still get Window if the data context isn't set... Am I missing anything?

Comment: UPDATE: yes, I am. "this" inside event handlers is now always an object (empty one if there's no data context). However, it's still Window inside helpers unless there's data context set...

Comment: Ah this got missed. I'll open a Github issue.

Answer (score 13):

The first parameter in the function is the event. So you could use the target of the event to grab your element.

```
Template.scores.events({
  'click .click-me': function (event, template) {
    console.log(event.target);
    $(event.target).text("O but I did!");
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Brandon. This is indeed one way to grab the element (although I would generally use currentTarget). However it doesn't answer my question: bug, docs or me?

Comment: I would say docs. Esp since meteor is still pre release. Docs are probably the hardest thing to keep up to date and to be fully inclusive. In situations like these, I just start adding params to the function and then console logging them. eg function (param1, param2, param3){ console.log(param1); console.log(param2); console.log(param3);}

Comment: You can get them all at once with console.log(arguments).

Answer (score 0):

A curious thing here I just discovered:

Here I have my template context in 'this':

```
Template.myTemplate.events({
    "click .my-select": function(e,t){
        console.log(this)
    }
});
```

But this variation (arrow) will put the Window object in 'this':

```
Template.myTemplate.events({
    "click .my-select": (e,t) => {
        console.log(this)
    }
});
```