# this.userId is undefined MongoDB property not inserted after submit

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I have the following event in my client file:

```
Template.categories.events({
...

  'keyup #add-category': function (e,t){
    if (e.which === 13)
    {
      var catVal = String(e.target.value || "");
      if (catVal)
      {
        lists.insert({Category:catVal,owner:this.userId});
        Session.set('adding_category', false);
      }
    }
  },
  ...
});
```

And this is the relevant template part:

```
<template name="categories">
    <div id="categories" class="btn-group">
        {{#if new_cat}}
        <div class="category">
            <input type="text" id="add-category" value="" />
        </div>

        {{else}}
        <div class="category btn btn-inverse" id="btnNewCat">&plus;</div>
        {{/if}} 
        {{#each lists}}
        <div class="category btn {{list_status}}" id="{{_id}}">     
            {{Category}}
        </div>
        {{/each}}
    </div>
</template>
```

So when a new Category is inserted, the owner should be set.. But it doesn't.

Here's the entry in MongoDB:

```
> db.lists.find()
{ "Category" : "test-admin", "_id" : "EsybjC3SLnNzCBx2t" }
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? (actually I'm following the "Getting Started with Meteor" book lending library example

**EDIT** it seems that:

```
console.log(this.userId);
undefined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swap this line:

```
lists.insert({Category:catVal,owner:this.userId});
```

to this one:

```
lists.insert({Category:catVal,owner:Meteor.userId()});
```

Comment: boom. Is it an API change from when the book was wrote? That's still the -current-logged-in-user ?

Comment: I'm not sure, if the context was `Meteor`, using `this` would work. The accounts framework is extremely recent (2 months), when was the book written? `Meteor.userId()` should get the logged in user

Comment: I am working on an app right now and `console.log(this.userId)` works for me in events

Comment: The issue might be similar to this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15137206/the-context-of-this-in-meteor-template-event-handlers-using-handlebars-for-te

Comment: I think you need to use the event for elements within `{{#each lists}}` to get the context of the object as `this`. Your event currently is out of the each loop. I am guessing this could be a problem. Worth replicating.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to put it inside the each lists.. It's a one-time input... shouldn't be looped. @Akshat: book very recent.. published no more than 1 month ago..

Answer (score 1):

`this` is probably not what you expect it to be inside that event. You should debug to confirm that that is the case. You are probably just getting undefined for `this.userId`. I would recommend assigning `this` to a variable (call it "self" or "that") outside of this event handler function but inside the scope where `this` will be what you actually want it to be. You can then reference that variable inside the event handler.

It should look like this:

```
function thatRegistersEvents() {
    var self = this;

    // ...

    registerSomeEvent(function () {
        return self.someThisProperty;
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Indeed it seems that this.userId is undefined (+1) but I think this may be caused by a problem in how I setup accounts/users in Meteor..

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct behavior. If you read the official Meteor documentation for references to `this.UserId`, it is only available in [`Meteor.publish()`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/publish_userId) and [`Meteor.methods()`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/method_userId). `this.UserId` is not available in `Meteor.template()`, which you have done in the code sample above, so one must use [`Meteor.userId()`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_userid) in templates.