# Using this in callback for non-collection

Tags: javascript, meteor, handlebars.js

I'm going through the [leaderboard](http://meteor.com/examples/leaderboard) example right now, and I've finished it, but I'm not fully satisfied with my implementation of the *add* functionality.

To start with, we have

```
Template.player.events({
    'click': function () { 
        Session.set("selected_player", this._id);
    }   
});
```

I find it a little bit confusing how `this` is associated with the player collection, but I imagine this has to do with the `<template` part.  I am also able to do

```
Template.leaderboard.events({
    'click input.delete': function () {
        Players.remove(this._id);
    }
```

...which does remove the player with the associated button entry.

---

Now for the actual question part: I have added this to the bottom of the leaderboard template:

```
<div>
    Add player: (Name <input required name="name" id="name">)
    (Score <input required name="score" id="score">)
    <input class="add" type="button" value="Add">
</div>
```

This works fine, and I have `Template.leaderboard.events['click input.delete']` working fine, but in order to get the values I use:

```
'click input.add': function () {
    var name = document.getElementById('name').value,
        score = document.getElementById('score').value;
```

It would make a lot of sense to me if I were able to use `this` in some way, or use the event to somehow get the values that correspond the inputs.  This not only makes sense to me from a design standpoint, but it would also cover the case of having more than one of these kinds of forms displaying simultaneously.

So in short is there any way to get elements that are near the target element in the context of an event?

Comment: Concerning your confusion with the **click** event: Inside a Template event handler, _this_ refers to the context of the current template instance. If I remember the _leaderboard_ example correctly, the context given to each Template.player instance is a document from the Players collection. **this._id** therefore gives you the MongoDB _id field that was auto-generated for that particular Player document

Comment: @travellingprog I think you're right, but in the `click input.add` event above, there is no Players collection context; it's outside of the `player` partial

Comment: Yep, so if you're in another template, then _this_ will give you access to that template's context.

Comment: @travellingprog that's nice ... so is there anything I can do to make the values of the `name` and `score` inputs somehow tied to the Leaderboard template (or some other template context that I can bind to?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every event handler is given two arguments: *event* and *template*. You can read more about these event handler arguments here: http://docs.meteor.com/#eventmaps

*event.target* is a reference to the DOM element that originated the event. You can then use something like jQuery's traversing functions to get an element nearby.

You could also set the input values as properties of the template instance. E.g. in the template's *created* handler, you create name and score properties:

```
Template.player.created = function() {
  this.name = '';
  this.score = '';
};
```

And then you update those values in the keyup events of your input textboxes:

```
'keyup #name': function(event, template) {
  template.name = event.target.value;
},

'keyup #score': function(event, template) {
  template.score = event.target.value;
}
```

This is the way the same way that widgets made for Ember update their values, as explained here: http://www.emberist.com/2012/04/12/two-way-binding-to-the-dom.html

Comment: What is the `template` argument used for?

Comment: It's a reference to the current instance of your template. You can assign properties to this instance in its _created_ handler, and instance also have certain functions. Read http://docs.meteor.com/#template_inst

Comment: I'll accept when I'm satisfied with the explanation; I was hoping to not use `event.target` but use some object that was associated with the template that the event is bound to and somehow unpack the values from that

Comment: you could've mentioned that you didn't want to use _event.target_ earlier. I'll edit my answer

Comment: It's not that I *don't* want to use `event.target`, I just want to find the most modular way of doing this.  Using `event.target` requires DOM analysis and knowledge of the DOM, but have a Model that is created from the elements automatically (at least by Meteor) makes more sense.  If using `event.target` is the only/best/standard way then that's okay, but `template` also looks interesting.

Comment: its supposed to be event.currentTarget isnt it? you can also use `template.find` to access the DOM on that specific template & `this` should also work, but it gives access to the data context, also at `template.data`

Comment: @travellingprog what does template.x = do? I'm not to sure that can work

Comment: It accesses property x on the current instance of the template, and you can create your own properties for the template in its _created_ handler. This is mentioned (albeit with no example) in the documentation: http://docs.meteor.com/#template_created. I did make a small mistake in that I used the _keypress_ event instead of _keyup_, I've updated my example. I also removed the use of jQuery for users who may avoid its use.

Comment: @travellingprog so you are saying that in `'click input.add'` I could access `template.name`/`template.score` since they are properly updated via the respective `keyups`?  There's no way to make that more ... automatic?

Comment: Not that I know of. You might wanna browse through the packages at [atmosphere](https://atmosphere.meteor.com/), but those non-core packages are used "at your own risk".

Answer (score 1):

Nice to see someone with so much street cred using Meteor! The best way to get the value is with [event.currentTarget](http://docs.meteor.com/#eventmaps) and to get stuff from the data contexts there is also another way which needs no DOM knowledge

```
Template.player.events({
    'keypress #name':function(event,context) {
        //Get the event sending this' value
        console.log(event.currentTarget.value)

        //Traverse the DOM on the template 'player' in this case
        console.log(context.find('#score').value)
     }
});
```

Basically the best way to get the value of the sender is to use `event.currentTarget` to access the DOM for that object sending the event.

The reason it's implemented this way is probably because any dom object can send an event and it won't necessarily always have a `value` field so a slight bit of knowledge of the DOM is required when handling the event maps but using `event.currentTarget.value` works for most form fields

**Data contexts**

Regarding the data contexts you should be able to use the data available in the templates from the helpers, e.g if theres a `{{score}}` & a `{{name}}` value in the template or a helper, which is passed in this case via the `{{#each}}` for each individual player.

```
 this.name,
 this.score;
```

Which is also the same as (I usually use `context` in my helper but `template` is another way of callng it i guess like in travellingprog's answer)

```
 context.data.name,
 context.data.score;
```

The `this` helps get data from the template's data context into event's so that one doesn't have to use hidden HTML attributes containing data, e.g with how the player is removed its a bit cleaner than storing the `_id` in the dom somewhere. That being said `event.currentTarget` or `context.find(..)` are the best way to get the data from a textfield.

Comment: In your case, the template's context in an event handler would be stored in `context.data`, which makes your name scheme confusing. Your variable `context` is actually a reference to the current instance of the template. Although, as you mentioned, if you want to retrieve the data context inside an event handler, you can just use `this`.

Comment: I use `context`/`template` because `this` won't always work in certain scenarios. It is a context based on the data available at that time so  hence why i prefer context. `this` will return the window as described here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15137206/the-context-of-this-in-meteor-template-event-handlers-using-handlebars-for-te/15149650?noredirect=1#comment21969567_15149650. It is more an issue with meteor but I prefer it because `this` sometimes confuses me with Sencha projects, as soon as the issue's fixed it will be consistently the data context where available

Comment: @Akshat well the `add` form is not per Player, just per Leaderboard (of which there is only one, though).  I think `context.find` makes more sense than `document.getElement`, but how do I guarantee a template's context?  Also is there any simple way to associate the name input(for example)'s value with `this.name` even when it's been changed by the user typing?  At least, any way simpler than what travellingprog suggested?