# Accessing data from outside events callback

Tags: meteor

```
<template name="SideNav">
  <ul class='block-items white'>
    {{#each blocks}}
      <li class='block-item'>
        <i class="fa fa-fw fa-folder"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-fw fa-folder-open"></i>
        <a href='#' class='block-item-link'>
          {{name}}
     ...
     {{/each blocks}}
</template>
```

Given this, I can access each block-item's `id` when it's clicked by doing

```
Template.SideNav.events({
  "click .block-item": function (e, tem) {
    //var blockItemId = this._id;
  }
});
```

How can I borrow the same feature from other places, like `onRendered()`? Take a look at the following example:

```
  Template.SideNav.onRendered(function() {
    this.$('.block-items').sortable({
      update: function (e, ui) {
        _.each($('.block-item'), function (blockItem) {
          // How do I get blockId?
        })
        console.log("block item rearranged");
      }
    });
```

`update` is a callback function that's invoked when there was a change in the order of block items in the `ul` list. I need a way to iterate through all the block items and get their corresponding Mongo `id`'s. How can I do it?

Related Documents:

1. [The context of "this" in Meteor template event handlers (using Handlebars for templating)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15137206/the-context-of-this-in-meteor-template-event-handlers-using-handlebars-for-te)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Update: the "Meteor way"

If you are looking for how Blaze gets this data context for events and helpers, it turns out there is a magical [`Blaze.getData()`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/blaze_getdata) function which takes a Blaze view **or** a DOM object and returns its data context. As far as I could tell by looking at the code, it seems to be the tool Blaze uses for providing data contexts to helpers and events.

So in your case, you could use:

```
  Template.SideNav.onRendered(function() {
    this.$('.block-items').sortable({
      update: function (e, ui) {
        _.each($('.block-item'), function (blockItem) {
          var context = Blaze.getData(blockItem.get(0));
          var blockId = context._id;
        })
        console.log("block item rearranged");
      }
    });
```

---

## Original answer

An easy way to get the id of a document when working with DOM manipulation (other than blaze events) is to explicitly set it as an attribute in your template, such as:

```
<template name="SideNav">
  <ul class='block-items white'>
    {{#each blocks}}
      <li class='block-item' id='{{_id}}'>
        <i class="fa fa-fw fa-folder"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-fw fa-folder-open"></i>
        <a href='#' class='block-item-link'>
          {{name}}
     ...
     {{/each blocks}}
</template>
```

This way, you can just fetch the id using jquery's `attr` method:

```
  Template.SideNav.onRendered(function() {
    this.$('.block-items').sortable({
      update: function (e, ui) {
        _.each($('.block-item'), function (blockItem) {
          var blockId = blockItem.attr('id');
        })
        console.log("block item rearranged");
      }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you BraveKenny. This is the way I am handling things right now, but I am unsure whether exposing Mongo object ID's to DOM id attributes is a good practice. Let's hear other people's opinions.

Comment: Sure thing. Personally I don't think you can do much better if you have to use jquery-ui for this. JQuery things need jQuery access to their data, as opposed to other tools provided by blaze. The difference with `onRendered` is that it is linked to the *parent* data context: it can know about its children blocks, but has no clue about *which* block your jQuery sortable is working on.

Comment: Yes. It doesn't seem the Meteor way to do it this way. But I am not sure what else I can do. I also use another jQuery library that forces me to store Mongo Object Ids as DOM element id attributes.

Comment: Updated my answer, it might interest you ;)