# MongoDB: Doing update for nested elements in document and removing specific nested object

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I need to remove some nested data in a document, which looks like this:

```
{
    "_id" : "123",
    "groupdata" : [
        {
            "title" : "group 1",
            "data" : [
                {
                    "description" : "row 1",
                    "many" : 2,
                    "other" : 0,
                    "fields" : 0
                },
                {
                    "description" : "row 2",
                    "many" : 2,
                    "other" : 0,
                    "fields" : 0
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "title" : "group 2",
            "data" : [
                {
                    "description" : "row 1",
                    "many" : 2,
                    "other" : 0,
                    "fields" : 0
                },
                {
                    "description" : "row 2",
                    "many" : 2,
                    "other" : 0,
                    "fields" : 0
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

In the frontend the data is displayed in a table. Each dataset of `groupdata` is a own table and each `data` is one row of the table. Each input name identical to the field-name in the mongodb document.

For saving changes I'm using for a change event on input:

```
var inputs = $(that).closest('tr')[0].getElementsByTagName('input'),
    indexGroup = $(that).closest('.panel').index(),
    indexDosis = $(that).closest('tr').index(),
    id = 123;

for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    field = $(inputs[i]).context.name;
    data[field] = $(inputs[i]).context.value;
}

setObject["groupdata."+ indexTable +".data"+ indexRow] = data;

Collection.update({ _id: id }, { $set: setObject }
```

I have one question and one problem:

1. Is the order of objects fixed, so that I can do that with `index()` or is the way how I do the update problematically? If this is not the best way, what do I have to change?
2. I need to remove one row, but the data-object itself don't have an unique id. So how can I remove a specific row (=data object) withour removing the other objects of the same array?

So in this example I want to remove the first row of the second table.

Comment: As to your second question, I think you are looking to use `this.` on the row that you want to delete. I vaguely remember using this.data to an {{#each}} block `event`. Try out this [video](https://www.eventedmind.com/feed/meteor-spark-data-annotation-and-data-contexts) and this [Stack thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15137206/the-context-of-this-in-meteor-template-event-handlers-using-handlebars-for-te)

Comment: But wouldn't `this` just give me the document, which I can also get with the id. But I need some specific nested objects. Or do I misunderstand that? I think both questions have the same basic problem: I need to get access to a nested object - wether for an update or removing (which would be an empty update for me)...

Comment: Nesting arrays is not a great idea. While you can `$push/$pull` elements atomically or even directly refer to items by set indexes, the assumption that an indexed position does not change is subject to a lot of failure reasons ( mostly by introduced code and not the database itself ) in real execution. Also there is the limitation of the [positional `$`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) operator in matching such structures by conditions. So while you can use set indexes, if something else changes this before the write, you get unexpected results.

Comment: What would be a better way? I also tried to use a model tree structure, which is much easier to update. But for reading it is much slower, as I need multiple elements for just one "article document". Because of reading/displaying the data is in this case more important for me, then writing I decided to use nested data, so every information, which I need is in one document.