# Change css background color on click in meteor

Tags: javascript, html, css, meteor

I am trying to change the background of the row in a table when a button is clicked. Currently my code will only change the background color for the first row in the table and only that first row. Even if I click the button of another row it still makes the first row background green.

How do I go about getting it to change the background for each individual row with it's corresponding button? (i.e. The button is in the row and when it is clicked that specific row will have its background color change)

Here is the html code for my table:

```
<template name="adminPage">
 ...
  <tbody>
    {{#each student}}
      <tr  class="accordion-toggle mainRow">
         <td>{{> expandButton}}</td>
         <td>{{Name}}</td>
         <td>{{PhoneNumber}}</td>
         <td>{{VipID}}</td>
         <td>{{> buttonSelections}}</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td colspan="12" class="hiddenRow">
 ...
</template>

<template name="buttonSelections">
 ...
  <button class="btn btn-success btn-sm">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"> Check-In</span>
  </button>
 ...
</template>
```

Here is the js code I have:

```
Template.buttonSelections.events({
  'click .btn-success, click .glyphicon-log-in'() {
   $(this).closest('.mainRow').css({"background-color":"#13D620","color":"white"});
   }
  }
})
```

So, the problem is within selecting the specific row. When I tried:

```
Template.buttonSelections.events({
   'click .btn-success, click .glyphicon-log-in'() {
     $('.mainRow').css({"background-color":"#13D620","color":"white"});
    }
  }
})
```

I get the following when I click any of the check-in buttons

[image]

Comment: Use class instead of id. `$('.mainRow').css('background-color', '#13D620');
    $('.mainRow').css('color', 'white');`

Comment: `id`s should be unique to your page. As such, you should avoid using them in loops unless you're "constructing" them from a unique value within the loop like you're doing with `id="{{this._id}}"`. Within your click event, you can access the [`this`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15149650/648350) property within your event handler function to "traverse" to the `closest` row and apply your changes. _PS_ you can provide an object to the `.css` function (eg. `.css({"background-color":"#13D620","color":"white"})`

Comment: @haxxxton I am still a little confused on how this will work in the context of my code. Everything I tried with this so far does not work. How would I need to reference the this property in order to get the row? I have tried things like `this.$('.mainRow).css(...);`

Comment: You would use `$(this).css(..)` instead of `$('.mainRow')`.. Based on your context you may need to "traverse" upwardly to select the row however (eg. `$(this).closest('.mainRow').css(...)`).

Comment: @haxxxton neither way seems to be working. Any other thoughts?

Comment: @E.Pace, if you can provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) I can help you debug.

Comment: @haxxxton So I added some stuff above. When I tried your suggestions nothing in the table changed to green. I don't think any other code is relevant to the problem past what is above.

Comment: when you `console.log(this)` what does it return? if it is an html element, you should be able to find the row you're looking for

Comment: @haxxxton when I do `console.log(this)` it returns an object with the contents of that particular row.

Comment: great.. have you tried `$(this).css(..)`?

Comment: @haxxxton Yes. console log gives the same output. When the button is pressed nothing happens.

Comment: when you say "_an object with the contents of that particular row_" is this an HTML object, jQuery object? is there a key in particular that identifies the html element?

Comment: @haxxxton No it is an object of the Collection that I am pulling data from. No references to html elements.

Comment: does it reference an individual element of the collection? or only the collection itself?

Comment: Only the collection itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the element clicked by hooking into the `event.target`.

```
Template.buttonSelections.events({
  'click .btn-success, click .glyphicon-log-in': function(e) {
   $(e.target).closest('.mainRow').css({"background-color":"#13D620","color":"white"});
   }
  }
});
```

Comment: Yep. That's it. Thanks a lot. I appreciate it.

Comment: :) we got there in the end