Unable to get data context from Template after rendering with #each in Meteor
I'm using blaze with Meteor.
Let's try the following simple setup:
    <template name="render_array>
      <ul class="list">
        {{#each items}}
          <li>{{this.itemdescription}}</li>
        {{/each}}
      </ul>
    </template>

In Template JS
   Template.render_array.events({
     'click .list':function(event, template){
        console.log(this)
     }
   })

   Template.render_array.helpers({
     'list':function(event, template){
        return [
          {name: "AA", description:"A for Apple"},
          {name: "BB", description:"B for Boring"}
        ]
     }
   })

console.log returns {}
I was expecting to get the object when I refer to this in the template event. Am I doing something wrong or this is not supposed to be expected?

I got the answer. The context of the html is wrong. What I needed to do was give the right context to the element I'm clicking on.
<template name="render_array>
  <ul class="list"> 
    {{#each items}}
      <li class="list-item">{{this.itemdescription}}</li> <!-- add list item -->
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
</template>

Template.render_array.helpers({
  'click .list-item':function(ev, template) {
     console.log(this) // returns the object
  })
})

Managed to solve it!

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15137206/the-context-of-this-in-meteor-template-event-handlers-using-handlebars-for-te?rq=1
Reading this led me to the answer - its about defining the context!
